# How to override only some functions in interface?

Tags: java

Actually, i have attended the interview. They ask me,

> There is a three functions in interface. overridden class only need to override only one function. how can you achieve this?

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: declare the class as abstract!

Comment: In Java 8, interfaces can have default implementations for their methods.  Is that the kind of interface you're dealing with here?

Comment: In Java 8 you can have default methods. Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use abstract class and implement some of the methods

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the other answer, an abstract method that implements an interface can choose to implement only some of the methods of that interface, leaving the implementation of the rest of the methods to its concrete sub-classes.

In Java 8 you can do it even with concrete classes, as interfaces can have default implementations for some of their methods. Therefore, only the methods that don't have default implementations must be implemented by concrete classes that implement the interface.

Comment: Either this is the correct answer, or the person asking wasn't specific enough when using the term "interface"

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the class implementing that interface as `abstract`.

But the class extending that abstract class has to implement all the methods declared in that interface that have not been overridden in the abstract class.